# How to receive multiple messages in HiveMQ Client? (MQTT)

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt, hivemq

I'm trying to figure out how to receive multiple messages in HiveMQ Client using the same try catch block even using different clients. I followed this example:

https://github.com/mqtt-bee/mqtt-bee-examples/blob/master/mqtt-3-blocking/src/main/java/org/mqttbee/examples/mqtt3blocking/Application.java

The above example works fine with one client and a single publish and subscribe but I'd like to perform multiple of these actions in the same block of the try catch if possible.

```
package com.main;

import java.util.UUID;

import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.MqttGlobalPublishFilter;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.datatypes.MqttQos;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5BlockingClient;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5BlockingClient.Mqtt5Publishes;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.Mqtt5Client;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt5.message.publish.Mqtt5Publish;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());  // Creates a logger instance 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Mqtt5BlockingClient client1 = Mqtt5Client.builder()
            .identifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) // the unique identifier of the MQTT client. The ID is randomly generated between 
            .serverHost("localhost")  // the host name or IP address of the MQTT server. Kept it 0.0.0.0 for testing. localhost is default if not specified.
            .serverPort(1883)  // specifies the port of the server
            .buildBlocking();  // creates the client builder

            client1.connect();  // connects the client
            System.out.println("Client1 Connected");

            Mqtt5BlockingClient client2 = Mqtt5Client.builder()
                    .identifier(UUID.randomUUID().toString()) // the unique identifier of the MQTT client. The ID is randomly generated between 
                    .serverHost("localhost")  // the host name or IP address of the MQTT server. Kept it 0.0.0.0 for testing. localhost is default if not specified.
                    .serverPort(1883)  // specifies the port of the server
                    .buildBlocking();  // creates the client builder

            client2.connect();  // connects the client
            System.out.println("Client2 Connected");            

            String testmessage = "How is it going!";
            byte[] messagebytesend = testmessage.getBytes();   // stores a message as a byte array to be used in the payload 


    try {  

        Mqtt5Publishes publishes = client1.publishes(MqttGlobalPublishFilter.ALL);  // creates a "publishes" instance thats used to queue incoming messages
                                                                                    // .ALL - filters all incoming Publish messages 
            client1.subscribeWith()  // creates a subscription 
            .topicFilter("test/something1/topic")  // filters to receive messages only on this topic (# = Multilevel wild card, + = single level wild card)
            .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  // Sets the QoS to 2 (At least once) 
            .send(); 
            System.out.println("The client1 has subscribed");

            client1.publishWith()  // publishes the message to the subscribed topic 
            .topic("test/something1/topic")   // publishes to the specified topic
            .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  
            .payload(messagebytesend)  // the contents of the message 
            .send();
            System.out.println("The client1 has published");


         Mqtt5Publish receivedMessage = publishes.receive(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // receives the message using the "publishes" instance waiting up to 5 seconds                                                                         // .get() returns the object if available or throws a NoSuchElementException 

         byte[] tempdata = receivedMessage.getPayloadAsBytes();    // converts the "Optional" type message to a byte array 
         System.out.println();
         String getdata = new String(tempdata); // converts the byte array to a String 
         System.out.println(getdata);

        client2.subscribeWith()  // creates a subscription 
           .topicFilter("test/something2/topic")  // filters to receive messages only on this topic (# = Multilevel wild card, + = single level wild card)
           .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  // Sets the QoS to 2 (At least once) 
           .send(); 
           System.out.println("The client2 has subscribed");

         client2.publishWith()  // publishes the message to the subscribed topic 
            .topic("test/something2/topic")   // publishes to the specified topic
            .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  
            .payload("The second message :P".getBytes())  // the contents of the message 
            .send();
            System.out.println("The client2 has published");  
          System.out.println();  


            // VV   Why isn't the publish instance below receiving the second message? Do i need another try catch?  VV

         receivedMessage = publishes.receive(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get(); // receives the message using the "publishes" instance waiting up to 5 seconds                                                                          // .get() returns the object if available or throws a NoSuchElementException 

         byte[] tempdata2 = receivedMessage.getPayloadAsBytes();    // converts the "Optional" type message to a byte array 
         System.out.println();
         getdata = new String(tempdata2); // converts the byte array to a String 
         System.out.println(getdata);        

    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {    // Catches interruptions in the thread 
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "The thread was interrupted while waiting for a message to be received", e);
        }

    catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        System.out.println("There are no received messages");   // Handles when a publish instance has no messages 
    }

    client1.disconnect();  
    System.out.println("Client1 Disconnected");

    client2.disconnect();  
    System.out.println("Client2 Disconnected");

    }
}
```

**The output I'm getting:**

Client1 Connected

Client2 Connected

The client1 has subscribed

The client1 has published

How is it going!

The client2 has subscribed

The client2 has published

There are no received messages

Client1 Disconnected

Client2 Disconnected

**The output I want:**

Client1 Connected

Client2 Connected

The client1 has subscribed

The client1 has published

How is it going!

The client2 has subscribed

The client2 has published

The second message :P

Client1 Disconnected

Client2 Disconnected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code and found this WARN log:

```
2019-06-11 20:32:22,774 WARN  - No publish flow registered for MqttStatefulPublish{stateless=MqttPublish{topic=test/something2/topic, payload=21byte, qos=AT_LEAST_ONCE, retain=false}, packetIdentifier=51, dup=false, topicAlias=0, subscriptionIdentifiers=[1]}.
```

It seems you forgot to set the publish filter for your second client. And indeed in the code where you are waiting for the second message (for client2) you check the message flow of client1.
So you just need to add a publish filter for client2:

```
Mqtt5Publishes publishesClient2 = client2.publishes(MqttGlobalPublishFilter.ALL);
```

And then wait for a message for client2:

```
// VV   Why isn't the publish instance below receiving the second message? Do i need another try catch?  VV

     receivedMessage = publishesClient2.receive(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS).get();
```

***Results:***

**Before:**

```
Client1 Connected
Client2 Connected
The client1 has subscribed
The client1 has published

How is it going!
The client2 has subscribed
The client2 has published

2019-06-11 20:46:36,537 WARN  - No publish flow registered for MqttStatefulPublish{stateless=MqttPublish{topic=test/something2/topic, payload=21byte, qos=AT_LEAST_ONCE, retain=false}, packetIdentifier=51, dup=false, topicAlias=0, subscriptionIdentifiers=[1]}.
There are no received messages
Client1 Disconnected
Client2 Disconnected
```

**After:**

```
Client1 Connected
Client2 Connected
The client1 has subscribed
The client1 has published

How is it going!
The client2 has subscribed
The client2 has published


The second message :P
Client1 Disconnected
Client2 Disconnected
```

Edit: I hope this is the solution you are looking for, as the wanted output is not the same as the one I get with the fix. As NoSuchElementException is not thrown/catched anymore. Therefore "There are no received messages" after the second message is missing.

Edit in response to comment: Snippet for collecting the publish messages for client2 with the async flavor (Just replace the code in your try block with the code below):

```
// The list where we put our received publish messages
            final List<Mqtt5Publish> incomingMessagesClient2 = new LinkedList<>();

            // With the async flavour we can add a consumer for the incoming publish messages
            client2.toAsync().publishes(MqttGlobalPublishFilter.ALL, mqtt5Publish ->
                    incomingMessagesClient2.add(mqtt5Publish));

            client1.publishes(MqttGlobalPublishFilter.ALL);  // creates a "publishes" instance thats used to queue incoming messages

            client2.subscribeWith()  // creates a subscription
                    .topicFilter("test/something1/topic")  // filters to receive messages only on this topic (# = Multilevel wild card, + = single level wild card)
                    .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)  // Sets the QoS to 2 (At least once)
                    .send();
            System.out.println("The client2 has subscribed");

            client1.publishWith()  // publishes the message to the subscribed topic
                    .topic("test/something1/topic")   // publishes to the specified topic
                    .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                    .payload(messagebytesend)  // the contents of the message
                    .send();
            System.out.println("The client1 has published");

            client1.publishWith()  // publishes the message to the subscribed topic
                    .topic("test/something1/topic")   // publishes to the specified topic
                    .qos(MqttQos.AT_LEAST_ONCE)
                    .payload("The second message :P".getBytes())  // the contents of the message
                    .send();
            System.out.println("The client1 has published");
            System.out.println();


            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);

            incomingMessagesClient2.forEach(mqtt5Publish -> System.out.println(new String(mqtt5Publish.getPayloadAsBytes())));
```

Best regards,

Michael from The HiveMQ Team

Comment: Thanks, that was the output that I expected and I fixed it in the question. As a follow up could you tell me if the below is possible.

Comment: Let's say client 1 publishes two messages to the topic: test/something1. If client 2 is subscribed to test/something1 can it receive all messages in some kind of list or container in just one line. Can we have all of the messages received put in a container? So far I've been using a Mqtt5Publish instance immediately after each publish() from another client to receive that message.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I added a simple code snippet in my answer that you can try it out.